# Regex to match the string

Tags: javascript, regex

can anyone tell me how to match the following string for regex in JavaScript.

```
Microsoft-Office-365-Bundle?formsAction=success&
```

Comment: `/Microsoft-Office-365-Bundle\?formsAction=success&/`

Comment: `.*` would match the string. I think we need more information about what part of the string you are interested in...

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific with the pattern that you shared, you can use the following regex:

`/^((\w)*-?)+\?(\w)+=(\w)+&$/`

Comment: This is matching `?=` or `%:;,?=~#{@@@@`

Comment: @Toto I have updated the regex to not allow such strings.

Comment: @Toto My bad, shouldn't have added the square braces. Let me know if you can still break the regex.